# Create pixel square and present later

Tags: python, sdl-2

I’ve started working with Python and SDL2 a short time ago to program my psychological experiments. My question, therefore, is probably very basic. 
I would like to create a square filled with random pixels of two different colors and show it in the middle of the screen. I’ve managed to create this pixel square and show it but it takes up to one second to create it. Thus, I would like to create the pixel square earlier, that is in a moment in which the participant is occupied with something else, and later show it. 
I thought about using SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0) twice but I was not able to do it. Is there a very easy way to solve my problem? Maybe it’s possible to save the created pixel square to a file and then load it later on? That’s how I create my pixel square:

```
def put_pixel(x,y, color):
      pixel = SDL_Rect(x, y,1,1)        

      if color == "orange":
          SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer,255,100,0,255) 
      elif color == "blue": 
          SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer,0,100,255,255)

      SDL_RenderFillRect(sdlRenderer,pixel)
      return sdlRenderer

def pixel_square(n_pixel_x,n_pixel_y, n_pixel_blue):

    seq = range(n_pixel_x*n_pixel_y) 
    random.shuffle(seq)

    lst = range(n_pixel_x*n_pixel_y)
    pos=0
    for i in range(n_pixel_x):
        for j in range(n_pixel_y):
                lst[seq[pos]] = [i,j]
                pos = pos+1 

    #create orange square   
    square_orange=SDL_Rect(MAXX/2-n_pixel_x/2,MAXY/2-n_pixel_y/2,n_pixel_x,n_pixel_y)    
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer,255,100,0,255) #orange
    SDL_RenderFillRect(sdlRenderer,square_orange)     

    #add blue pixels
    for i in range(n_pixel_blue):
       put_pixel(x=MAXX/2-n_pixel_x/2+lst[i][0], y=MAXY/2-n_pixel_y/2+lst[i][1], color="blue")      

    return sdlRenderer
```

Later on I use

```
SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer)
```

to show the pixel square.

I’d be very happy if you could help me with that problem!! 
Thank you! 
Vero

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure to create images is slow due to the overhead of calculations and loops to process. Aside from optimizing them here and there and precomputing, storing and loading images from elsewhere, I'd recommend to use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/%20%22Numpy) to generate the image on the fly, if applicable. It features random distribution arrays out of the box and is heavily optimized for speed.

A fully working example could look like:

```
import sys
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext
import numpy

SIZE_X = 400
SIZE_Y = 300

# RGB values
RED = 0xFF0000
GREEN = 0x00FF00

def pixelate():
    choices = [RED, GREEN]
    pixelarray = numpy.random.choice(choices,(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))
    buf = pixelarray.tostring()
    # Create a software surface from the array. The depth and pitch are really
    # important here, since we use a continuous byte buffer access.
    image = sdl2.SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(buf,
                                          SIZE_X, SIZE_Y,
                                          32,   # Bit depth, we use 32-bit RGB
                                          SIZE_X, # pitch (byte size of a single scanline) - for 32 bit it is SIZE_X
                                          0xFF0000,
                                          0x00FF00,
                                          0x0000FF,
                                          0x0)
    # required to avoid loosing buf. SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() will
    # reference the byte buffer, not copy it
    image._buffer = buf
    return image

def main():
    sdl2.ext.init()

    window = sdl2.ext.Window("Pixel example", size=(800, 600))
    imgoffset = sdl2.SDL_Rect(200, 150, 0, 0)
    window.show()

    # Software rendering, we also could use hardware rending and use streaming
    # textures, but the example would become more complicated then.
    windowsurface = window.get_surface()

    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                image = pixelate()
                sdl2.SDL_BlitSurface(image, None, windowsurface, imgoffset)
        window.refresh()
        sdl2.SDL_Delay(10)
    sdl2.ext.quit()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The most important part is the *pixelate()* function, which creates a 2D array of specified size filled with a random distribution of the passed values (your colors). SDL2 allows you to create surfaces (images) from a byte buffer, so the next step is to create a buffer from the 2D numpy array and create a surface using that specific buffer.
Once done with that it is a simple matter of showing the image on the screen.

If [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/%20%22Numpy) can't be used in your environment, I would avoid to draw each pixel individually using your *put_pixel()* method, since this will cause at least one context switch on each color change in the SDL2 renderer (worst case). Instead, precompute a 2D array, fill it with the necessary values and create a software surface buffer (or again, a streaming texture) based on it, which you then blit on the screen in a single operation.